# Rewriting a text object

Tags: unity, gui, text

I'm trying to set up a UI system. Say I have a text object 'text' which is visible onscreen. I want to change it with a button press using a script such that the text box's previous string is replaced with a new string held in a string variable 'chat'.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class textchange : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text text; //the text box gameobject is dragged into this

public string chat; //the chat string is filled elsewhere

void Awake()
{

}

void Update()
{
(if button press logic here)
{
text.text = chat;
}
}

}
```

What I expect is for the text to dynamically change, but what happens is absolutely nothing, the gameobject does not have its text component rewritten. What gives?

Comment: I suspect the "button press logic here" is done wrong. Did you try putting a `Debug.Log` line inside the function to see if it runs?

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, but I've also got a boolean set up to just light up when the logic is successful (i.e. button is registered and processed correctly) to check against and it's fine.

Comment: Based on the exchange below, it looks like this was just a null reference exception error. If you get different errors or unexpected behaviour after fixing your exception, please edit your question to include all relevant details and we can re-open it for fresh answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here looks correct at first glance, but there might be a mistake in the `button press logic here` part you omitted.

Verify that the line `text.text = chat;` is actually being executed. You can do that by adding a line like `Debug.Log("changing content of " + text.name + " to " + chat)` in front of it and looking at the console output or by setting a debugger breakpoint in Visual Studio and running the game in debug mode.

It is also possible that you didn't assign a text field to the `public Text text` variable. The symptom would be a `NullReferenceException` error in your Unity console whenever the line `text.text = chat` is being executed. Open the inspector of the game object with this script and drag the text field you want to control into the "Text" slot of your component.

Comment: In my console I get: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Script.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Script.cs:47), where line 47 is text.text

Comment: @Woksjnak Then you likely didn't assing a text object to the public text variable in the inspector of your game object. In the future, please check your console before you post a question and mention any error messages you get.